# Validating format in Python (Example: check PAN number is valid)

Tags: python, python-2.7, validation, python-3.x, formatting

**How to check and validate the format of input in Python.**

For example - How to validate the format of PAN number using python. In PAN number first five values should be alpha next four values should be a numeric last value should be alpha. (Ex: **abcde1234a**)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this,

```
def validate_pan_number(value):
    """
    Validates if the given value is a valid PAN number or not, if not raise ValidationError
    """
    if re.match(r'^[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]$', value):
        return True
    else:
        raise ValidationError(
            '%(value)s is not valid PAN number',
            params={'value': value},
            )
```

Obviously there is no `ValidationError` in python, the above is implemented for django, and here is the [desciption](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/exceptions.py#L100) of ValidationError

Answer (score -5):

First method to validate the format of PAN number using python

[image: First method to validate the format of PAN number]

or you can do like this also
[image]

Comment: It's considerably easier with regex: `/[a-z]{5}\d{4}[a-z]/`

Comment: Please, no screenshots of code. Post the code itself